# Getting the common elements between JSON and array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json

I now have a JSON string:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"good","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.440Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.440Z"},{"id":2,"name":"better","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.447Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.447Z"},{"id":3,"name":"best","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.449Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.449Z"}]
```

And I have an array:

```
id = ["1", "3"]
```

I want to check for the common IDs and print the associated name. For the above example I want my output to be:

```
 ["good","best"]
```

I want the output preferably to be an array. Is there a easy way to do this? I have been writing too much code to get this done and feel it should be easily done. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of asking us to write code from scratch that will have no resemblance to your code, you should provide a sample of your code and we can tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# initiate json string
json = %q([{"id":1,"name":"good","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.440Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.440Z"},{"id":2,"name":"better","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.447Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.447Z"},{"id":3,"name":"best","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.449Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.449Z"}])

ids = ["1", "3"]

JSON.parse(json).select{|x| ids.include? x["id"].to_s}.map{|x| x["name"]}
#=> ["good", "best"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'

def pluck(json, ids)
  json_parsed = JSON.parse(json)

  json_parsed.select do |obj|
    ids.include?(obj['id'])
  end
  .map do |obj|
    obj['name']
  end
end

# usage
json = '[{"id":1,"name":"good","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.440Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.440Z"},{"id":2,"name":"better","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.447Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.447Z"},{"id":3,"name":"best","created_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.449Z","updated_at":"2014-07-28T19:45:50.449Z"}]'
ids = [1, 3]
pluck(json, ids)
```

Comment: It's idiomatic to use curly-braces instead of `do`/`end` when using `select` and `map`.

Comment: Just trying to keep it under 60 chars / line. I prefer vertically spread code better.

Comment: O I see what you mean. I guess I could've used {} also vertically.

Answer (score 0):

in you controller can do this:

```
def  method_name

  render json: Model.pluck(:name).to_json

end
```